# How one deals with typedefs in Squeak FFI

Tags: smalltalk, ffi, squeak

I want to interface with a library (HDF5) which uses exclusively its own typedefs in both function prototypes and structure definitions.

```
typedef struct {
    H5L_type_t          type;           /* Type of link                   */
    hbool_t             corder_valid;   /* Indicate if creation order is valid */
    int64_t             corder;         /* Creation order                 */
    H5T_cset_t          cset;           /* Character set of link name     */
    union {
        haddr_t         address;        /* Address hard link points to    */
        size_t          val_size;       /* Size of a soft link or UD link value */
    } u;
} H5L_info_t;
```

In Visualworks with DLLCC I can deal with such typedefs like this:

```
H5Interface>>hbool_t
    <C: typedef unsigned int hbool_t>
```

And I can then use `hbool_t` in both prototypes and structure, same for enum.

But Squeak FFI seems to understand only a few atomic types and interpret anything else as a structure. Obviously, someone has to do the translation, and if it is not automated, then it's both errorprone and not robust to future evolutions of external library.

So what is the recommended way for avoiding such fragility?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an obscure feature for handling aliases (typedef)

Create a new ExternalStructure class

```
ExternalStructure subclass: #'Hbool_t'
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'FFI-Tests'
```

Then create fields method with nil and aliased type

```
Hbool_t class>>fields
    ^#( nil 'ulong' )
```

Do `Hbool_t defineFields` and now 'Hbool_t' is a registered type, and can be used in other structure definition and in function prototypes.

It's not exactly 'hbool_t', but it is better than direct replacement by ulong.

Answer (score 1):

Since mt.92, you can also subclass `ExternalTypeAlias` to document type aliasing in a clear fashion. See [source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.92.diff](http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.92.diff)

You example alias could use the new base class:

```
ExternalTypeAlias subclass: #'Hbool_t'
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'FFI-Tests'
```

The class-side just needs the original type name, which is the one you are aliasing:

```
Hbool_t class>>originalTypeName
    ^ 'ulong'
```

Note that `Hbool_t defineFields` will also define the accessors `#value` and `#value:` to resolve the alias at runtime.

Also note that external structures with fields using that alias will create instances even for aliases to atomic types:

```
H5L_info_t>>corder_valid
    <generated>
    ^ Hbool_t fromHandle: (handle unsignedLongAt: 123456)
```