# How one supports both 32 and 64 bits target in Squeak FFI

Tags: smalltalk, ffi, squeak

I have to deal with an external library that has this kind of definition `struct foo {float *data; size_t len;};`

First I define corresponding structure in Squeak

```
ExternalStructure subclass: #Foo 
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'FFI-Tests'.
```

Then Squeak FFI can deal with different pointer sizes.
I know that I will have to re-generate the field access thru a `Foo defineFields`.
But that's something that I can handle in package loading postscript for example.

Unluckily, there is no `size_t` support in Squeak FFI. On the platforms I want to support, I know it will be uint32_t and uint64_t, which translates to `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` respectively in Squeak FFI (those types are fixed size viewed from Squeak image size).

So what should I do? Have two different definitions of Foo (but then I must duplicate all the types using foo and the interfaces for the prototypes using foo)

```
Foo32 class>fields
    ^#(
        (data 'float*')
        (len 'ulong')
      )


Foo64 class>fields
    ^#(
        (data 'float*')
        (len 'ulonglong')
      )
```

Or is there any other solution (like defining manually the fields/offsets/byteSize with `Smalltalk wordSize=4 ifTrue: [] ifFalse: []` for example)?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you how to do this in Squeak, but I can share with you the approach we took in the Smalltalk dialect I use.

1. Have shared variables for each the fields associating the field name to its offset within the structure
2. By default have all such offsets work for, say, the 32 bit target platform
3. Write the accessor methods using these shared variables (instead of literal numbers)
4. Have an `#offsets64` class-side method that answers with the dictionary of offsets for 64 bit
5. At start up, if the system is running 64-bit, use the `#offsets64` dictionary to replace the values of the shared associations with the 64-bit offsets. This requires no conditional logic on the accessors and no recompilation of methods. It also works well if the relative positions of the fields changes with the platform.

Note that steps 4 and 5 are only required if the structure layout depends on the bit length (which is not always the case).

All of this can be simplified if your system supports "local pool dictionaries", which are pool dictionaries with the scope of class variables.

Comment: That's useful, but the offset would have to be auto-generated and this would require deeper change of FFI itself. For now, I indicate a less powerful but working solution with current FFI.

Answer (score 1):

Since mt.101, you can also use lightweight aliases for atomic types, which are implemented as messages on `ExternalType class`, usually in the "type constants" protocol. See [source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.101.diff](http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.101.diff)

There are already common aliases for typedefs known from `<stddef.h>` and `<stdint.h>` such as `size_t` (or `uintptr_t`), which you can use in field definitions for external structures and argument definitions for FFI calls.

Your example can now be written in a cross-platform way:

```
Foo class>>fields
    ^ #(
        (data 'float*')
        (len 'size_t')
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I discovered the aliases (typedef) as reported at [How one deals with typedefs in Squeak FFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783882/how-one-deals-with-typedefs-in-squeak-ffi/49798663#49798663) I see a solution:
define a Size_t alias

```
ExternalStructure subclass: #'Size_t'
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'FFI-Tests'
```

then define platform dependent fields:

```
Size_t class>>fields
   ^(Smalltalk wordSize = 4)
       ifTrue: [#( nil 'ulong' )]
       ifFalse: [#( nil 'ulonglong' )]
```

Then do `Size_t defineFields`, and now I have a Size_t type that I can use in function prototypes and for composing other struct. The layout will differ on 32 and 64 bits images, but I will not have to change the client code.

It's a bit more problematic for platform specific 'unsigned long' because of LLP64 on Windows 64bits which is among the supported platforms:

```
ExternalStructure subclass: #'Unsigned_long'
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'FFI-Tests'

Unsigned_long class>>fields
   ^(Smalltalk wordSize = 4 or: [Smalltalk platformName = 'Win64'])
       ifTrue: [#( nil 'ulong' )]
       ifFalse: [#( nil 'ulonglong' )]
```

I'll then have to check for a change at platform at image startup and recompile all the ExternalType.
This recompilation must be performed with the right order, and once again, I do not see any support for that in Squeak FFI, that will deserve some more work...

**EDIT** I have modified Squeak FFI for introducing automated recompilation support when resuming an image on another platform, along with correct initialization order for nested structures.
See http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-nice.49.diff

Comment: Having an ABI object will also help. The amount of places where you have to ask for the word size is very high, so it's much more elegant to ask the current ABI object (SysVx86ABI, SysVX64ABI, Win64ABI, etc) for things like the pointer type

Comment: Since mt.75, there is FFIPlatformDescription, which implements automated recompilation on startup when the platform changed.
See http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-mt.75.diff